# Problema ao enviar um projeto para o GitHub

Tags: github

Olá, tudo bem ? Estava enviando um projeto para o github e acabei encontrando um problema que ainda não tinha acontecido comigo.

```
error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/xxx/xxx'
```

Pesquisei para encontrar a resposta, inclusive há respostas no próprio stack overflow, **porém em inglês**, que eu tentei me basear neles e solucionar mas não tive sucesso.
Se alguém conseguir me ajudar, ficarei muito grato !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente inicializar o git primeiro dentro da paste que está o seu código.

```
git init
```

Depois adicione um arquivo qualquer, pode ser um README.md

e realize o commando `git commit -m "seu commit aqui"`

depois faça o comando `"git push origin master"`

provavelmente irá funcionar.

Comment: $ git push origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'origin'  
infelizmente apareceu esses erros, sabe me informar o que pode ter sido ?

Comment: Digite o comando 'git status', e veja o que retorna.

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado !!